# RN IOS: Import of module 'glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google'

Tags: ios, react-native, build, glob

This question has been asked multiple times on stack overflow however none of them have produced a solution for me.

As the title states. When I try to build my app on xcode I get this error:

> Import of module 'glog.glog.log_severity' appears within namespace 'google'

The error occurs in logging.h file in the google namespace.

```
namespace google {

// They need the definitions of integer types.
#include "glog/log_severity.h"
#include "glog/vlog_is_on.h"
```

I have tried adding the following line of code to my podlock file:

```
use_modular_headers!

pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

I have tried each of these separately and in combinations with each other.

Has anyone found another solution to this?